# Index Out of range Cell[Col=13 Row=1]. помогите найти ошибку (Lazarus)

Tags: delphi, lazarus

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]не могу понять где ошибка всего колонок 12, а строк 31 (Dies), а во втором случае Cumulus 3 колонки и 100 строк, при этом код порограммы правильно записан. И также в второй форме наоборот 100 колонок и 3 строки

```
const My1color : array[1 .. 100] of integer = ($90EE90,$20B2AA, $00FF00, $FF00FF, $0000CD,
   $00FA9A, $FFA500, $B22222, $CD853F, $B0E0E6, $ADFF2F, $4169E1, $DEB887, $5F9EA0,
   $7FFF00, $D2691E, $FF7F50, $DC143C, $B8860B, $A9A9A9, $9932CC, $8B0000, $2F4F4F,
   $FF1493, $B22222, $FF00FF, $DAA520, $ADFF2F, $FF69B4, $E6E6FA, $32CD32, $00FFFF,
   $7FFFD4, $F0FFFF, $FFE4C4, $0000FF, $8A2BE2, $A52A2A, $DEB887, $5F9EA0, $7FFF00,
   $FF7F50, $6495ED, $FFF8DC, $DC143C, $00FFFF, $008B8B, $B8860B, $A9A9A9, $006400,
   $BDB76B, $8B008B, $556B2F, $FF8C00, $9932CC, $8B0000, $E9967A, $8FBC8F, $483D8B,
   $2F4F4F, $00CED1, $9400D3, $FF1493, $00BFFF, $696969, $1E90FF, $B22222, $FFFAF0,
   $228B22, $FF00FF, $F8F8FF, $FFD700, $DAA520, $FF69B4, $CD5C5C, $F0E68C, $E6E6FA,
   $FFF0F5, $7CFC00, $FFFACD, $ADD8E6, $F08080, $FFB6C1, $FFA07A, $20B2AA, $87CEFA,
   $778899, $B0C4DE, $FFFFE0, $00FF00, $32CD32, $FF00FF, $800000, $66CDAA, $BA55D3,
   $3CB371, $7B68EE, $00FA9A, $FF4500, $FF0000);   

v:= 1;
for w:= 1 to 31 do
begin
   Chart3BarSeries1.Addy(StrToInt(StringGrid10.Cells[1,w]),StringGrid10.Cells[1,w], TColor(Mycolor[v]));
end;
```

Все равно не понимаю на что он ругается, помогите пожалуйста понять в чем проблема

Comment: Нумерация cells случайно не с нуля идёт?

Comment: нумерация у всех 3 случаев начинается с 1, я новичок в этом деле , может нужна какая то формула подсчета в данном случае чтобы такие ошибки  не совершать?

Comment: Ну вы всё-таки проверьте, существует ли ячейка с нулевым индексом

Comment: сейчас код скину в виде скриншота чтобы вы сами увидели

Comment: Нумерация Cells в StringGrid идёт с 0. Там могут быть фиксированные строки и столбцы, тогда ячейки с данными начинаются с 1, но в этом случае их должно быть 13 и 32, соответственно. Т.к. заголовки - это просто ячейки, которые иначе рисуются.

Comment: спасибо, за ответ )) все получилось )